# A doubt in M. Hall paper(On the number of Sylow subgroups in a finite group). Please help.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

It is the equation 2.5 in the theorem 1 of the paper [Hall](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/243016139_On_the_number_of_Sylow_subgroups_in_a_finite_group*1).

I am mentioning the theorem below-

**Theorem** ([M. Hall]) Let $K \unlhd G$, $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $n_p=a_pb_pc_p$, where 
$a_p = \#Syl_p(G/K)$
$b_p=\#Syl_p(K)$ and 
$c_p=\#Syl_p(N_{PK}(P\cap K)/(P \cap K))$.

If you can't see the paper, just consider just this equality in proof of the theorem, as this is the only part i don't get.

$\textbf{Problem-}$          If $G$ is a finite group and $K\triangleleft G$ and $P$ is a sylow $p-$ subgroup of $G$, then he writes this equation,

$P\cup (N_{PK}(P)\cap K)=N_{PK}(P)\cap (P\cup K)=N_{PK}(P).$

Now out of these 2 equalities, first one is clear to me, but problem is, how he is writing the second equality i.e. $N_{PK}(P)\cap (P\cup K)=N_{PK}(P)$.

I have seen it from alot many many angles, discussed it with my professor, cant write all my attempts here, have spent many hours on it, but nothing. please help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does $P \cup K$ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by $P$ and $K$? If so, then the claim is trivial because $PK \le P \cup K$ (and in fact $PK = P \cup K$, because $K \unlhd G$).

Comment: but notation for that is $<P,K>$ i.e. join, and if he  is using $\cap$ as intersection, $\cup$ should be union. although he never mentions it in paper anywhere that what $\cup$ is?

Comment: In his book, Marshall Hall uses $H \cup K$ meaning subgroup join $\langle H,K \rangle$. He is using $\cup$ as a lattice operation for join in the lattice of subgroups. I am sure that is what he means here. It cannot possibly mean union, because the union of two subgroups is not usually a subgroup.

Comment: yeah. then he must mean this. thanks

Comment: may in 70's $\cup$ was the standard notation for join.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sir, will you please take a look at this [Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/944948/a-question-on-p-groups-and-order-of-its-commutator-subgroup) and my attempt, I haven't got any answers on this one.

Comment: Why would the claim be trivial? As you say, $P \cup K = PK$ and since $PK \subseteq N_{PK}(P)$ it should be $P \cup ( N_{PK}(P) \cap K) = PK$. In fact, it does not make sense that Hall tries to establish that $<P, N_{PK}(P) \cap K > =  N_{PK}(P) $

Comment: Okay, got it, my mistake: $PK \subseteq N_{PK}(PK)$ and not $PK \subseteq N_{PK}(P)$ and indeed $N_{PK}(P) \subseteq PK$

Answer (score 0):

So, what he is saying is this: $P(N_{PK}(P) \cap K)= N_{PK}(P) \cap PK= N_{PK}(P)$, use modular law* for first equality. Since $P \subseteq N_{PK}(P)$, $N_{PK}(P) \cap K \triangleleft N_{PK}(P)$ and $P\cap (N_{PK}(P) \cap K)= P\cap K $, this gives $N_{PK}(P)/N_{PK}(P) \cap K \cong P/P \cap K$.

Modular law: if $pk=x$ with $p \in P$, $k \in K$ and $x \in N_{PK}(P)$, then $k = p^{-1}x \in N_{PK}(P)$ so $k \in N_{PK}(P) \cap K$.