# Is it true that the derived series of $G/G^{(n-1)}$ is of length $n-1$, where $n$ is the length of the derived series of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups, derived-subgroup

Consider a group $G$ and its derived series $$G=G^{(0)}\trianglerighteq G^{(1)} \trianglerighteq \ldots \trianglerighteq G^{(n-1)} \trianglerighteq G^{(n)}=\{1\}\,.$$
Is the derived series of $G/G^{(n-1)}$ is of length $n-1$? At first, I thought that it was clear because I thought that the derived series of $G/G^{(n-1)}$ was $$G/G^{(n-1)} \trianglerighteq G^{(1)}/G^{(n-1)}\trianglerighteq G^{(2)}/G^{(n-1)}\trianglerighteq \ldots \trianglerighteq G^{(n-1)}/G^{(n-1)}=\{e\}$$
But I'm not so sure if this is correct.

Comment: It is correct. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39124/the-commutator-subgroup-of-a-quotient-in-terms-of-the-commutator-subgroup-and-th?rq=1 for the proof that $(G/G^{(n-1)})^{(i)}= G^{(i)}/G^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: Thank you. This helped